# user authentication for whois.domaintools.com python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, urllib2, whois

i am trying to develop python script to get hosting company info from domaintools.com, below is my script. somthing wrong with this authentication part it returns 403 error.

```
domain_tools_url = 'https://secure.domaintools.com/log-in/'
username = 'username@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
sys.path.append("./BeautifulSoup")

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, domain_tools_url, username, password)
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener=urllib2.build_opener(authhandler, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=0))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
url = "http://whois.domaintools.com/62.75.xxx.xxx"
page = opener.open(url)
```

can i know how to fix this issue,

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) makes this a lot nicer - might be worth a try. Basic auth is just `requests.get('http://example.com', auth=('user', 'pass'))`

Comment: Hi @AlexL, Thanks for your replay. i have installed requests lib and i have run below script it returns [Response 200]  
In [6]: requests.get(domain_tools_url, auth=(username, password))
Out[6]: <Response [200]>   then how can i process this url = "http://whois.domaintools.com/62.75.xxx.xxx"

Comment: after authentication it returns 403 response  'In [9]: requests.get("http://whois.domaintools.com/62.75.xxx.xxx", auth=(username, password))
Out[9]: <Response [403]>

In [10]: requests.post("http://whois.domaintools.com/62.75.xxx.xxx")
Out[10]: <Response [403]>'

Comment: Can you log in manually? 403 means that you're getting refused

Comment: yes from browser i can login using same auser credentials

Comment: Using basic auth? Or via a login form? If the latter, you could use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Comment: Did you ask your provider? Also please use example IPs from RFC5737 for documentation purposes instead of useless and wrong obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

> then how can i process this url = "whois.domaintools.com/62.75.xxx.xxx"

Instead of parsing the html, I suggest using domaintools own API to get the data you need in a straight way without detours (3rd party libraries)

http://www.domaintools.com/api/

DomainTools offers 500 whois queries/month for free, and subscriptions if you need more.

```
import urllib.request
import json

# please take notice that this is only a sample query 
# you usually need to authenticate your request: http://www.domaintools.com/api/docs/authentication/
data = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen('http://freeapi.domaintools.com/v1/domaintools.com/whois/').read().decode('utf-8'))

def readValues(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        print(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for value in obj.values():
            readValues(value)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            readValues(item)

readValues(data)
```

it's in Python 3, fyi